# Where is $SOLR_HOME in SOLR 6.6.2?

Tags: security, solr, basic-authentication, solr6

I am trying to setup Basic Authentication for SOLR, and trying to follow their instructions: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html

I created the `security.json` file, and now it says that I am supposed to put it in the $SOLR_HOME directory, if the instance is a standalone instance (which it is).

Where exactly is **$SOLR_HOME**? I googled to see that it's supposed to be where the `solrconfig.xml` or `schema.xml` file is, but because SOLR has multiple cores, those files exist in EVERY conf folder in EVERY core. So where is this file supposed to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$SOLR_HOME should be configured to point to the root of the cores and there should be a corresponding "solr.xml" in that location. You can copy the solr.xml from the Solr install directory under /server/solr/solr.xml

Edit: Clarifying what I mean by "root of the cores". The parent folder. If you have multiple cores; each core will be contained in it's own folder. The $SOLR_HOME is the parent folder to these.

Comment: The path is also printed in the server log when starting Solr: `Using system property solr.solr.home: /[....]/server/solr`

Answer (score 1):

$SOLR_HOME is where a new core is placed when it's created as well. In our case, the default install made that /var/solr/ with each core inside /var/solr/data/[corename].